# is it possible to limit number of points per segment

Tags: spatstat

I have network of approx 8K segments each of 20m. A random poisson process creates a realization on this network. Next I want to add another poisson process but the points from second process should not fall on segments that are already containing points from first process.

Q1> Largely, I am curios to know if points per segments can be defined. My understanding is this is not possible because of the properties of poisson process. But may be there is a optional argument to limit points per segment? I know it is possible to limit number of points on the whole linnet object, but I am wondering if this is possible per segment of linnet.

Q2> I thought of excluding the segments with points from the first process.  My understanding is that I cannot exclude segments from a linnet because the the network gets disconnected / disjoint and this is not preferred in spatstat.

Please correct me on these two issues.
Currently I plan to use random poisson but later when some surveys are finished, I will use covariates to model intensity of points.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by avoiding locations picked by the first process? If you are just talking about the exact locations it is already very unlikely that a previously picked point will be chosen unless you have massive amounts of data. These are random double precision numbers so there is room for **a lot** of distinct points along the linear network.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have huge data set, about 8K line segments. But you are right I have to structure my model differently, because currently I pick whole segment if there is a point realized on it and same segment gets picked twice. thanks for the clarification. But I request just one last clarification, it is possible that I can say one point per segment  (my segments are length 25-50m) ? I know it not possible, but may be there is some hidden optional argument? Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. What do you mean by "I pick the segment"? Are you making a model that just picks segments at random and you don't need to put points on the segment? Maybe edit your question and add details about what you want to achieve and what you have done so far and what the problem with that is.